# Drawing a line where the mouse went

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, mouse, line

Basically, I want to draw a line where the mouse goes, like in paint, but, when I draw a dot over the mousePos every tick, this happens:

[image: This happens]

Now, I need some help turning this into a line, that doesn't have gaps or anything weird.
Thanks for helping.

The code I'm using to generate the lines (This is not the code for in the picture!)

```
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        Line newLine = new Line(pixel, point1, point2, 2, Color.White);
        allLines.Add(newLine);

        foreach (Line lines in allLines) 
        {
            lines.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

and the line object:

```
    public class Line
{
    Texture2D texture;
    Vector2 point1, point2;
    float width;
    Color color;
    float angle, length;

    public Line(Texture2D texture, Vector2 point1, Vector2 point2, float width, Color color) 
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.point1 = point1;
        this.point2 = point2;
        this.width = width;
        this.color = color;
        angle = (float)Math.Atan2(point2.Y - point1.Y, point2.X - point1.X);
        length = Vector2.Distance(point1, point2);
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) 
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, point1, null, color, angle, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(length, width), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a curve instead, or do you really mean a line?

Comment: Probably, if you show the actual code will be of help

Comment: Have you tried using a path (object) rather than using a point? If you make a path and then set a point on the path when the mouse moves, no matter how fast you move the mouse, the graphical representation should remain constant and smooth.

Comment: @Servy Well, I basically, just want to draw a line where the mouse goes, it can be a curve, but also be a line, depends where you move the mouse to.

Comment: @NathanWheeler I tried using a line object, but I'm not sure how to set both of the positions, I know that I have to set point1 to the current mousePos, but what does the other one have to be? If I put it on the current mousePos, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Steve I'll put the code I'm using in now.

Comment: You'll want to save the previous coordinates as the start of the line and use the current coordinates for the end of the line. Then update the old coordinates after you've drawn it.

Comment: @Stan - I meant path, not line. A line has 2 points, start/end. A path has a start point, then multiple points along the length, then an end point. I did something like this a long time ago (over a year) with XAML/C# and it worked incredibly well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your going to want to do is something like this (expanding on pathfinder666's answer):

```
private Point _lastPoint;

protected void MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
    g.LineTo(_lastPoint.X, _lastPoint.Y, e.X, e.Y);
    _lastPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

Now keep in mind, this might look a little jaggedy. You may want to use [DrawArc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142028.aspx) instead to smooth it out a little. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish in the end.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done in the past when I needed to draw lines/paths based on mouse movement is to use the Path objects rather than lines.

Here's a XAML/C# example. Just start a new XAML project in C#, and paste this into the default "MainWindow":

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private PathFigure _pathFigure = new PathFigure();
    PathFigureCollection _pathCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
    PathSegmentCollection _segments = new PathSegmentCollection();
    private PathGeometry _pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _pathFigure.Segments = _segments;
        _pathCollection.Add(_pathFigure);
        _pathGeometry.Figures = _pathCollection;
        myPath.Data = _pathGeometry;
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            LineSegment segment = new LineSegment();
            segment.Point = e.GetPosition(this);
            _pathFigure.Segments.Add(segment);

        }
    }

    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _pathFigure.StartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
    }
}
```

---

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestPaths.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid>
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Name="myPath" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**Output**

[image: MainWindow from PathGeometry Example]

This example doesn't make you any new paths, so the line jumps when you press the left mouse button again (to the current position). It would be extremely simple to add the functionality to make new paths as needed.

This sample does eliminate the need to keep a rolling track of new points, as your last point is always available in the existing objects. For more information about paths, including how to set in curves and such, see the [PathGeometry Docs on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

how about you you keep last point in memory and draw the line from that last point to the current point. you might have to smoothen out the curve to make it smooth and visually appealing.

Comment: Using a path, you just add a new line/curve to the end of the geometry, thus eliminating the need to keep end/start points in memory all the time.